# Facebook oauth verification process in signup flow

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-oauth

I want to let users sign up via Facebook or email/password. In both cases I ask for their first name, last name and email address in the signup flow; but if they sign up via Facebook I pass the data from the User object client-side to the form fields so that they are pre-filled. There is one more field: accepting our terms and conditions.

Once the user authenticates with Facebook and has accepted the t&cs, they need to click the confirm button. This then triggers my server-side verification (PHP) to make sure that the form is validly filled and then take care of creating the user in the DB, the session variable "logged in" etc.

My question is the following: **what do I need to do on the server side to make sure the user I am getting in my POST data is indeed the one who authenticated via FB?** Should I pass the access token as a hidden form field and use the FB PHP SDK to check that the email in the form and the email in the User called via PHP are the same and that the token corresponds to my app? Or is there a better way to do it?

The Facebook doc is very fuzzy on this subject, with many options, tons of links and no clear picture.

Answer (score 0):

Well [Google](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow) explains it very well so I'll use that flow.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you just need to retrieve the User object on the server and  verify the POST data against it.

Using Graph API it doesn't matter if you authenticate using the client api or the server api, because the share the same authentication.

You just have to make sure that this redundancy in retrieving the same data on the server and the client is really needed.